# How do I rotate a shape in CSS3 but not rotate the text inside the shape?

Tags: css

Just getting started out in CSS3 and had a beginner question (first question on stackoverflow!). I've created four little shapes that rotate and change color when you hover over them. Inside each shape is a text box with a phrase like "About" or "Contact." How do I make it so that when I hover, the text box does not rotate but the shape around it does? I imagine I'll have to counter-rotate my span the same degrees as the shape rotates, but I'm having trouble doing this. I know the spacing is funny on the shapes, but I'm just setting this up as an exercise for myself. I'll address all the cosmetic things once I've figured out the rotation problem.

```
.burst-12 {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
opacity: .8;
top:100px;
border-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15 16 17 18px;
}

.burst-12:before, .burst-12:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
background: inherit;
}

.burst-12:before {
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
border-radius: 18px;
-moz-border-radius: 18px;
-webkit-border-radius: 18 19 17 16px;
}

.burst-12:after {
-webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
border-radius: 19px;
-moz-border-radius: 19px;
-webkit-border-radius: 19 10 11 16px;
}

.x1{
  background: #f64260;
}

.x2{
background: #f8605b;
left:123px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.x1:hover{
background-color:#94dbdd;
-webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.x2:hover{
background-color:#4c6278;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.x3 {
background-color: sandybrown;
left:190px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.x3:hover{
background-color:cornflowerblue;  
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.x4{
background-color: #f1ce4b;
left:260px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.x4:hover{
background-color:#305578;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.burst-12 span{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}

p:first-letter{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
color: white;
font-family: "Adobe Caslon Pro", "Hoefler Text", Georgia, Garamond, Times,     serif;
letter-spacing:0.1em;
text-align:center;
margin: 30px auto;
text-transform: lowercase;
line-height: 145%;
font-size: 14pt;
font-variant: small-caps;
border-style:solid;
border-width: 1px;
padding: 4px;
}
```

Here's my jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mthrasher33/bdh8sybj/

Thanks!

Comment: How about rotating the text the same amount the other way :) ? -300deg

Comment: I can rotate the text -300 when I hover over it by using the p:hover command and that works, but I don't know how to rotate it -300 when I just hover over the shape in which the text is contained. Does that make sense? Thanks for your response, Amin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you can count-rotate the text:

```
.x1:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-300deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-300deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-300deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-300deg);
}
```

This is what that would look like: https://jsfiddle.net/bdh8sybj/1/

And if you want to keep the text in the same position, you can use CSS3 translate:

```
.x1:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-300deg) translateY(-8px) translateX(-8px);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-300deg) translateY(-8px) translateX(-8px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-300deg) translateY(-8px) translateX(-8px);
         -o-transform: rotate(-300deg) translateY(-8px) translateX(-8px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bdh8sybj/2/

Comment: I was still typing the exact same answer! :D